# ¿Es correcto anidar paréntesis en una frase?

Tags: gramática

Si quiero anidar pensamientos con paréntesis (tiendo a abusar de ellos sin querer (deformación profesional)), ¿es correcto en español?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No tiene nada de malo, sin duda. Si vas a anidar algo dentro de una proposición que ya esté en paréntesis, [debes usar los corchetes](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Par%C3%A9ntesis#Usos) [ ] o las rayas para evitar así los equívocos a los que la repetición de paréntesis puede inducir.

> Si dentro de un paréntesis es necesario intercalar una nueva aclaración, esta aparecerá entre corchetes.

Por ejemplo:

*«Una de las telenovelas de mayor arraigo popular que produce Televisa lo es 'Cuna de lobos' (la que muchos consideran el mejor culebrón mexicano [producido por Carlos Olmos] de todos los tiempos), programa que en su momento paraliza y cautiva a una audiencia mexicana enorme»*

No te miento; yo por mi parte optaría por no formular una oración tan ofuscada por la ortografía.

Comment: Además en muchos contextos, es estilísticamente más apropriado usar la [raya](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raya_(puntuaci%C3%B3n)). En otros, es suficiente con usar la [coma](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_(puntuaci%C3%B3n)) o en ocasiones simplificar la construcción de la frase para usar un [punto y coma](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_y_coma).

Comment: ¡Vaya! Al revés que en matemáticas, donde si hay que anidar el corchete se pone por fuera del paréntesis.